# Book about an alien spaceship visited by human beings and adapting to them

Tags: story-identification, aliens, spaceship, artificial-gravity

Once the astronauts get on the ship, it starts to change to fit the human beings needs. The gravity and the atmosphere change, the structure of the ship's instruments changes as well etc. Finally, the ship becomes fully useful for human beings, because all it needs is to trap the astronauts and use them for fulfilling its goal - travelling the Universe. I read this book some time about 1981/1982. The book's title may be "The Ship" or "Relic", I'm not sure, but I can't find any book titled like this and with the story I wrote above.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_%28novel%29?

Answer (score 1):

Not Arthur c Clarke's rendezvous with rama?

The ship does change according to the needs of occupants, and occupants figure out how to interface with spaceship "operating system" to fabricate clothing, food and other materials

Comment: Rendezvous With Rama was my first thought, but in that story, the alien ship has no need for humans or additional crew at all - its purpose is left a mystery.

Comment: Clarke did end the Rama series with Rama revealed, where the eagle explains to Nicole what the ships are for. When the Eagle shows the characters the "factory", he shows where ships are built and modified explains how and why the ships change to fit the need of pasengers. Maybe that's it?

Comment: EDIT. Rama revealed was published in the 90s.